# Have to reduce /dev/xvda1 Memory in amazon ec2 server

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm new to the amazon server. In amazon ec2 server many times i could not do any operations because of /dev/xva1 memory. I have checked it by using the following command .ie.,

```
df -h
```

it shows the `/dev/xvda1            7.9G  7.9G     0 100% /`

I have changed amazon ec2 instance type from m1.medium to m2.xlarge still it is not getting resolved. Can any one help me for this issue.

Comment: /dev/xvda1 is the root disk volume (not memory).  Switching instance types will not change the size of the root volume.  You need to either increase the size of the volume or, better, trim unneeded files that are taking up space.

Comment: This might be better asked on serverfault.com

Comment: @Eric Hammond - thanks for your instructions. I have reduced the space by deleting some unwanted packages. Can you please explain how to increase the memory of the root volume and also how to find the unwanted files.

Comment: @Kalai It's been said to you it's not memory, but hard drive.

Comment: +Kalai: It looks like you found instructions on how to do it with the AWS console.  Here's an article I wrote on how to resize the root EBS volume with command line tools: http://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by increase the root partition size for my amazon instance. please refer the following url for increasing the partition size of the amazon instance

http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2012/05/07/resizing-root-partition-on-linux-in-amazon-ec2/